# Edit clipboard text without losing format style and run script continuously

Tags: macos, background, format, applescript, clipboard

I'm using this AppleScript to edit my clipboard data. But there are some things I couldn't figure out how to do:

1. This script removes the whole format-style of the text in the clipboard. Is there a way to preserve all the formats?
2. I tried to run this script as an application (with stay open checked on saving) but it just works once after a fresh start and doesn't edit any new copied text. How can I get this script to run continuously?

Here's my script:

```
on idle

    get the clipboard
    replacement of "SqlConnection" by "OleDbConnection" for the result
    replacement of "SqlDataAdapter" by "OleDbDataAdapter" for the result
    set the clipboard to (replacement of "SqlCommand" by "OleDbCommand" for the result)

end idle

on replacement of oldDelim by newDelim for sourceString
    set oldTIDs to text item delimiters of AppleScript
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to oldDelim
    set strtoks to text items of sourceString
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to newDelim
    set joinedString to strtoks as string
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to oldTIDs
    joinedString
end replacement
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to maintain formatting is frankly to use a styled text editor like Text Edit or Pages as an intermediate stage and manipulate it there.  i.e. open a new document in Pages, paste your text, do a find and replace to modify the text, select all using GUI scripting and then copy it back to the clipboard.

You can use this technique as well to setup a styled template, fill in database information, and then either print it or put it on the clipboard.  I use this quite a lot.  I just wish you could do it with Numbers.  (Number's find and replace has no keyboard option)

**Edit**: Here's a quick and dirty sample script to use Pages as an intermediary place to find and replace text that will maintain formatting.

```
tell application "Pages"
    activate
    make new document
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Pages"
        -- paste clipboard
        keystroke "v" using (command down)
        -- go to top of document
        key code 126 using (command down)
        -- open find window
        keystroke "f" using (command down)
        -- set word to replace
        keystroke "original"
        -- tab to replace field
        keystroke tab
        -- set word to replace with
        keystroke "newword"
        -- press replace all button
        click button "Replace All" of tab group 1 of window "Find & Replace"
        -- close find window
        keystroke "w" using (command down)
        -- select all text
        keystroke "a" using (command down)
        -- copy back to clipboard
        keystroke "c" using (command down)
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: If I use Pages or anything like that, then I'm back at beginning, which means replacing everything by hand (of course I use find/replace but I have to do by myself and that's exactly why I started using applescript - to prevent that. It's kind of odd when replacing the same 3-4 words again and again on shot texts)

Comment: No that's exactly what you don't have to do.  You can programmatically do a find and replace.  Just use GUI scripting to do it - I'll see if I can't whip up a script later tonight demonstrating that.

Answer (score 2):

First, applescript only works with text, not formatted text. So once you bring the clipboard into applescript you have lost all formatting. Nothing you can do about that. Second, in order for the "on idle" handler to work you need to return a time value, which is the time when the handler will run again. So just before the "end idle" statement add "return 10" which means run the script every 10 seconds.